# how to add new row to pandas dataframe based on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say, I have the below data frame as sample.

```
    name  age  status  price
0  frank   12       1    100
1   jack   33       0    190
2    joe   22       1    200
******************************
```

Desired output:

```
    name  age  status  price
0  frank   12       1    100
1   jack   33       0    190
2   jack   NaN      0    -190
3    joe   22       1    200
******************************
```

I also posted the sample data frame below, so you can test it easily.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "name":["frank", "jack", "joe"],
        "age": [12, 33, 22],
        "status": [1,0, 1],
        "price": [100,190, 200]
})
```

As you can see, I want to insert a new row based on the above row, which `status` is 0, it's meant to be a transaction failure. to statistics more easily, I want to generate a new row below that one. I also want its `price` to be negative number. and since I don't care about whole column of the new row, so I want the other column be `NaN`, just like 'age' here in my desired output.

What I've tried so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "name":["frank", "jack", "joe"],
        "age": [12, 33, 22],
        "status": [1,0, 1],
        "price": [100,190, 200]
})

df2_list = []

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row["status"] == 0:
        origin_row = row.to_dict()
        new_row = ({
                "name": origin_row.get("name"),
                #"age": origin_row.get("age"),
                "age": np.NaN,
                "status": origin_row.get("status"),
                "price": -origin_row.get("price"),

            })
        df2_list.append(new_row)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_list)
# concat df1 and df2 and sort it .
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
df4 = df3.sort_values(['name', 'price'], ascending=[True, False])
print(df4)
```

I have a loop, and check if it hit my condition `status==0`, and append it on my tmp list, and ...but it's too many code. I want to know is there any good way, I mean more Pythonic code or pandas has already got some function can it ?

Comment: Are names unique?

Comment: @coldspeed yes sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numpy.repeat` to add rows, and `Series.duplicated` to set the price.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df.status.eq(0)+1, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
df2.loc[df2.name.duplicated(), 'price'] *= -1
df2

    name age status price
0  frank  12      1   100
1   jack  33      0   190
2   jack  33      0  -190
3    joe  22      1   200
```

If you need to mask NaNs in the age column as well, you can do that with `Series.mask`.

```
df2.age.mask(df2.name.duplicated())

0     12
1     33
2    NaN
3     22
Name: age, dtype: object
```

---

Full code.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df.status.eq(0)+1, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
isdup = df2.name.duplicated()
df2.loc[isdup, 'price'] *= -1
df2['age'] = df2['age'].mask(isdup)

df2
    name  age status price
0  frank   12      1   100
1   jack   33      0   190
2   jack  NaN      0  -190
3    joe   22      1   200
```